# Ubuntu 22.04 losing wifi connection everday at the same period

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ipv4

The wifi of my Ubuntu 22.04.1 works normally for most of time. But, recently, each day at around 21:45 to 22:45, I will lose the connection to my apartment's public wifi from my laptop.

Strangely, when it happens, my phone can connect to the public wifi, and my laptop can connect to my phone. It looks like both my laptop and the public wifi are normal.

Actually, I have dual boot on my laptop. The windows system shows that there is no valid IP configuration for the wifi connection.

In the linux system, when the problem is happening, I tried `ping 8.8.8.8`, the result is `ping: connect: Network is unreachable` ; also tried  `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

The output from `nmcli dev status` is:

```
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION      
wlo1          wifi      connecting (getting IP configuration)  The_public_wifi 
p2p-dev-wlo1  wifi-p2p  disconnected                           --              
lo            loopback  unmanaged
```

The output from `ifconfig -a`:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 132086  bytes 86843282 (86.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132086  bytes 86843282 (86.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::23d6:f0e3:f98e:a7d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:32:17:59:b9:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2541136  bytes 3228770450 (3.2 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 25  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1109303  bytes 257645148 (257.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It seems that there is no IPV4 address is assigned to my laptop at this strange 1 hour long period as indicated by the diagnosis report from the Windows system.

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually your ISP will renew the external IP address once in 24 hours. But that should last not longer than 5 min.  You'll have to ask the guys that maintain the "public wifi". Your phone will use the mobile connection and not the wifi, and internal connections will still work.. I'd say not an "Ubuntu" problem

Comment: Hi, @kanehekili, probably it's true. But my phone is connecting to the same wifi

Comment: Maybe. But how to you know that your phone is **using** the wifi connection and **not** your mobile network data connection ?

Comment: Because I closed my mobile network connection